# Can't connect to external database with Codeigntier

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want Codeigntier to connect to a MySQL database on another server (not localhost). How do I configure this in the config/database.php file?

I set the hostname to the ip address with the proper username/password but it's not working.

The error I get says:

> A Database Error Occurred: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Comment: Can you connect to the remote mysql server from the command line on the local server? (I.e., via the mysql command?) It's possible you need to grant privs for that specific host.

Comment: Does your remote database server allow external connections? Maybe you need to check your firewall settings or your database user settings

Comment: Like Alex and Liam told you, this might be a problem with external connection permissions. If you are you using cPanel you can add a wildcard "%" on "Remote MySQL". If this doesn't work, contact your tech support.

Comment: yes i connect through command line, so it does not have to do with firewall settings.  I specified the port as well by adding an additional line to the database config file.  But still doesnt work.

Comment: and the error you get says...

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Comment: @bruce182: Next time you suggest an edit, please take the time to fix the various typos as well.

Answer (score 3):

Heru, it seems like you simply want to change the current DB configuration from localhost to your live server. Do this, open up your `database.php` file in the `application/config` folder. Then find these lines.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = ''; // might be empty or might be full 
$db['default']['database'] = 'your_database';
```

and change it to this . . .

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'your_host_name'; 
$db['default']['username'] = 'your_user_name';
$db['default']['password'] = 'your_password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'your_new_database';
```

depending if your on a shared host or not and other factors. Your host may provide you with a new host name , may require a password and may provide you with a pre-configured database name. Look into the host provider for these pieces of information.

**if that doesn't work . . .**

You could also try to change it to this which finds your servers IP and converts it to a named address, but your database may or may not be sitting on a different address. But it's worth a shot.

```
$hostIP = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
(string)$hostname = gethostbyaddr($hostIP);

$db['default']['hostname'] = $hostname; 
$db['default']['username'] = 'your_user_name';
$db['default']['password'] = 'your_password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'your_new_database';
```

also if your confident of your database IP, change the above

`(string)$hostname = gethostbyaddr($hostIP)`

to

`(string)$hostname = gethostbyaddr('10.11.12.123'); // with your IP #`

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as a database permissions issue, not a CI issue. You're probably not authorized to connect from your IP. What happens when you run this on some random PHP page:

```
mysql_connect($server, $un, $pw) or die( mysql_error());
```

To fix this, simply run:

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, UPATE, INSERT ON $dbname.% TO $un@% IDENTIFIED BY ('$pw')
```

Answer (score 0):

Triq,

You can add another set of database config to your `config/database.php` file (on top of your `default` set) like the following (you can change `dbwrite` to other name that you like):

```
$db['dbwrite']['hostname'] = "[other db host]";
$db['dbwrite']['username'] = "[other db username]";
$db['dbwrite']['password'] = "[other db password]";
$db['dbwrite']['database'] = "[other db name]";
$db['dbwrite']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['dbwrite']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['dbwrite']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['dbwrite']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['dbwrite']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['dbwrite']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['dbwrite']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['dbwrite']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Then, you can pull this db reference using the following code:

```
$dbw = $this->load->database('dbwrite',TRUE);
$dbw->query(xxx); // this will execute the query on the other db
```

Make sure `dbwrite` is the same name that you are using on your other db config. `$this` refers to `$CI` instance.

Comment: this does not solve the issue, I want to just change the current configuration I have right now not add a new one.

Comment: current config points to a local db I want to connect to another one on anotehr server

Comment: @triq I wonder if you've tried using a regular php file with `mysql_connect` function just to test out?

also when you test out using the command line, what user privilege are you using (root?)?

Answer (score -1):

```
You can easily Crated multiple database connection using codeigniter

    $db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost:3306";
    $db['default']['username'] = "root";
    $db['default']['password'] = "";
    $db['default']['database'] = "buy599_erp";
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRU`enter code here`E;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
    $db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

    $db['magento6']['hostname'] = "localhost:3306";
    $db['magento6']['username'] = "root";
    $db['magento6']['password'] = "";
    $db['magento6']['database'] = "magento6";
    $db['magento6']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $db['magento6']['dbprefix'] = "";
    $db['magento6']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['magento6']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['magento6']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['magento6']['cachedir'] = "";
    $db['magento6']['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $db['magento6']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['hostname'] = "localhost:3306";
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['username'] = "root";
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['password'] = "";
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['database'] = "magento6stalkbuylove";
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['dbprefix'] = "";
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['cachedir'] = "";
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $db['magento6stalkbuylove']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```